# If $X$ is a subset of $A$ with more than $n$ elements, then there exist $a,b \in X$ such that $ a \mid b $ or $b \mid a$.

Tags: proof-explanation, pigeonhole-principle, foundations

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leq x \leq 2n \} $. Prove: If $X$ is a subset of $A$ with more than $n$ elements, then there exist, $a, b\in X $ such that $a \mid b$ or $b \mid a$. (Hint: If $a \in A$, then $a = 2^jm $ with $m$ odd and $ m \in A$.)

My prof said this was a classic pigeonhole principle type of proof. However, I am not seeing the pigeonhole principle type of proof here, nor do I know how to approach it to prove it.

If someone could give me some hints as to how to start this I can keep trying and update this post to reflect my attempts. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $A$ you have $n$ odd numbers. Every number can be written as $2^jm$ with $m$ odd and $j\geq 0$. So if you have at least $n+1$ numbers in $X$ it means you have decompositions $2^{j_s}m_s, s=1,\ldots,n+1$. Here at least one odd number has to come twice since there are only $n$ odd numbers to go around. So let $a=2^{j_a}m$ and $b=2^{j_b}m$ be such a pair. Then either $j_a\geq j_b$ or $j_b\geq j_a$ which is equivalent to $a|b$ or $b|a$.

Comment: "Every number can be written as $2^jm$ with $m$ odd and $ j \geq 0$. Will you @Snake707 explain? I am having a hard time understanding this. In addition, will you explain why "at least one odd number has to come twice"?

Comment: If you have an odd number $m$ you can write it as $2^0m$. If you have an even number you can divide it until you get an odd number (stopping at 1). The last part is the pidgeonhole principle.

Comment: Ok. I tried a concrete example to try and understand the pigeonhole part. Let $n = 3$, we have $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \}$ and $ |X| \geq n + 1 \implies |X| \geq 4$. Suppose $|X| = 4$. Since $X \subseteq A$, then pick all the even numbers and one odd number, say 1. We have $X = \{2, 4, 6, 1\}$. This does not seem to imply that $X$ would have an odd number twice. Am I thinking about this wrong? @Snake707?

Comment: I did not say that you pick out all the even numbers and an odd number. What I said was to look at the decomposition: In your example of $X=\{2,4,6,1\}=\{2^1\cdot 1, 2^2\cdot 1,2^1\cdot 3, 2^0\cdot 1\}$ the odd remainder (what was previously termed $m$) is pidgeonholed. In this particular example $1$ appears three-fold.

Let $X=\{1,3,5,6\}=\{2^0\cdot 1, 2^0\cdot 3, 2^0\cdot 5, 2^1 \cdot 3\}$. In this particular example $3$ appears twice. You always end up with more odd remainders, than there are odd numbers => You have at least one odd remainder appearing twice.